# Displaying directory content in html page with python

Tags: python, html

I want to write a program in python which can read the files under a directory and can show them as hyperlink in a html page created by python program dynamically , can anyone please suggest i am newbie for python.

Comment: `os.listdir(directory)` will get you a list of all the files. From there, putting the file names into a HTML document should be fairly easy.

Comment: Your question has two separated parts; reading a directory's files and showing them as a hyperlink in an HMTL web-page. For the first part, you can easily use this: `[f for f in os.listdir(dir) if os.path.isfile(f)]`. But for the next step, I can't actually help you until you explain me how you exactly want to render the HMTL.

Comment: You can use Django if you want to write a server-side script to have an active web-page, but I don't know your objective. You can also use lxml lib along with an xlst file to render and update a local file periodically.

Answer (score 0):

## Quick hack using SimpleHTTPServer

Go to the directory, you want to have listing of and run:

with Python 2.7:

```
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

with Python 3.x:

```
$ python -m http.server
```

This will start local simple HTTP server on port 8000.

Visit `http://localhost:8000` and you will see listing of the current directory, which is even browsable.

Warning: Using this solution can be a security risk, as all the files are accessible for whoever visits published url.